# How to show $\lim_{x \to \sqrt{3}^+}\sqrt{x^{2}-3}=0$

Tags: real-analysis

I understand that given any $\epsilon>0$, I need to find a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - \sqrt{3}|<\epsilon$ whenever $0 < x - \sqrt{3} < \delta$.

Starting with $|\sqrt{x^{2}-3}|$, how do I simplify this to show this is $< \epsilon$ for an appropriately choosen $\delta$ using $0 < x - \sqrt{3} < \delta$?

Comment: Are you sure you mean $x \to \sqrt{3}^-$ and not $x \to \sqrt{3}^+$?

Comment: @aras That is what I meant, it is a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to show that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $x- \sqrt{3} < \delta$ (this is where the $\sqrt{3}^+$ comes in!) implies $\sqrt{x^2 - 3} < \epsilon$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Pick $\delta = \min(1, \frac{\epsilon^2}{1+ 2\sqrt{3}})$.

Assume that $x - \sqrt{3} < \delta$. Then we have $x+ \sqrt{3} < \delta + 2\sqrt{3}$, so taking their product,

$$ x^2 - 3 < \delta(\delta + 2\sqrt{3}) .$$

Sinc $\delta = \min(1, \frac{\epsilon^2}{1+ 2\sqrt{3}})$, in particular $\delta \leq 1$. So $\delta + 2\sqrt{3} \leq 1 + 2\sqrt{3}$, which means that

$$ x^2 - 3 < \delta (1 + 2\sqrt{3}) $$

Now use that $\delta \leq \frac{\epsilon^2}{1+ 2\sqrt{3}}$ to get

$$ x^2 - 3< \epsilon^2$$

and thus $\sqrt{x^2 - 3} < \epsilon.$

---

**Edit: Here's some motivation behind this real analysis black magic.**
You're given $x - \sqrt{3} < \delta$ and want $\sqrt{x^2 - 3} < \epsilon$. First of all, notice that $\sqrt{x^2 - 3} = \sqrt{x - \sqrt{3}}\sqrt{x + \sqrt{3}}$. The $\sqrt{x - \sqrt{3}}$ goes to $0$, but the $\sqrt{x + \sqrt{3}}$ term doesn't. It sort of hovers around $\sqrt[4]{3}$. Ideally, we'd like to do something like the following:

$$ x - \sqrt{3} < \delta \implies (\sqrt{x - \sqrt{3}})\sqrt{x + \sqrt{3}} < \epsilon .$$

So it seems natural to "solve" for the part we know, $x - \sqrt{3}$, to get

$$ x - \sqrt{3} < \frac{\epsilon^2}{x + \sqrt{3}} $$

Now this should start to look familiar. We're almost done! If we would be able to set

$$ \delta := \frac{\epsilon^2}{x + \sqrt{3}} $$

we'd have a proof. Unfortunately we need to get rid of the $x$ in the denominator.

Specifically, we need some lower bound for $\frac{1}{x + \sqrt{3}}$ that's a number independent of $x$. Luckily, since $x$ is "close" to $\sqrt{3}$, $\frac{1}{x + \sqrt{3}}$ won't grow without bound anywhere. To bound this denominator, we'll additionally require that $\delta \leq 1$. This gives us

$$ \frac{1}{x + \sqrt{3}} \geq \frac{1}{1 + 2\sqrt{3}},$$

so by requiring

$$ \delta = \frac{\epsilon^2}{1 + 2\sqrt{3}} $$

our proof will stay correct.

The way to formally write this is

$$ \delta := \min(1, \frac{\epsilon^2}{1 + 2\sqrt{3}}) .$$

Comment: Thank you so much, you've been very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The statement appears somewhat confused. This limit would be equivalent to showing for any $\epsilon > 0 $ there is a $\delta >0$ such that $|\sqrt{x^2-3}| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < x-\sqrt{3}  < \delta$.

Some hints: $\sqrt{x+y} \leq \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$ and $|x+y| \leq |x|+|y|$.

Comment: I don't know how to avoid the problem with the negative in the middle using your hint.

Comment: Or alternatively I think one can factor $\sqrt{x^2-3}=\sqrt{(x-\sqrt{3})}\sqrt{(x+\sqrt{3})} $ and try to bound the latter term in the product.

Comment: @100110 we certainly have $x < \delta +\sqrt{3}$. Thus $|\sqrt{x^2-3}| <|\sqrt{(\sqrt{3} + \delta)^2 -3}|$. Can we use the hints from here?

Comment: @SZN Yes, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @100110 Great! A further small comment: you need to argue that $\sqrt{x^2-3}$ is monotonic (that is $x < y$ implies $f(x) < f(y)$) to strictly use the substitution. This function certainly is monotonic but for instance showing $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\sqrt{1-\sin(x)} = 1$ would need extra work to use a similar method.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x \to \sqrt{3}^+}\sqrt{x^{2}-3}=\lim_{x \to \sqrt{3}^+}\sqrt{(x-\sqrt3)(x+\sqrt{3})}=\lim_{x \to \sqrt{3}^+}\sqrt{x-\sqrt3}\sqrt{x+\sqrt{3}}$

Now when $x \approx \sqrt{3}$

$\sqrt{x+\sqrt3}\sqrt{x-\sqrt{3}}\approx\sqrt{2\sqrt3}\sqrt{x-\sqrt3}$

Now consider what happens when $x\rightarrow\sqrt{3}^+$

Answer (score 1):

We have that $0<x-\sqrt{3}< \delta$.

Take $\delta<1$

Thus $|\sqrt{x^2-3}|=|\sqrt{x+\sqrt{3}}||\sqrt{x-\sqrt{3}}|<|\sqrt{2 \sqrt{3}+ \delta}||\sqrt{x-\sqrt{3}}|< \sqrt{2 \sqrt{3}+ \delta}\sqrt{\delta}<(\sqrt{2 \sqrt{3}+ 1}) \sqrt{\delta}$

Finaly you can take $\delta=\min\{\frac{\epsilon^2}{\sqrt{2 \sqrt{3}+1}},1\}$ and you are done.